# What is the value range of _score (relevance) in ES function_score?

Tags: elasticsearch

While trying to use `function_score` with `boost_mode: "sum"` (because it makes it easier to trace different contributions), I want to normalise query relevance's effect on overall document score, but for that I need to know what values can it take. At first I assumed `(0, 1)`, but it's clearly not so as I also see scores above `1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the query that you are wrapping and the number of records in the index. The way lucene calculates the score is [quite complicated](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#package_description) and it's difficult to predict the range in a general case. I would recommend using `multiply` as a `boost_mode` instead of `sum`, it typically produces better results.